# Sublime Text Shortkeys on different keyboard layouts

Tags: keyboard, sublimetext2, keyboard-shortcuts, sublimetext, sublimetext3

Before posting an enhancement request to Sublime Text on Github I was thinking that this could possibly be solved with a package. Perhaps someone even already know of a solution I have not been able to find.

An example:

Sublime Text 3 keyboard shortcut for Toggle comment: `Ctrl` + `/`
That's what it says in the menu too.

However, the keyboard shortcut on a Swedish keyboard layout is `Ctrl` + `-`
(because `-` is where the `/` is on an english keyboard layout...)

So, can anyone think of a way to make it so that Sublime Text shows the correct information (by making a package or, maybe someone knows of one)?

Comment: This is also kinda same with a german keyboard - i tried to remap all the shortcuts i find usefull - but there are really to much of them so no luck - may they can add a feature where one can select a keyboard layout which does the remapping - i asked them but didn't get an answer yet

Comment: Just to say that there's an open issue (as today March 10, 2016) on GitHub for this issue: https://github.com/SublimeTextIssues/Core/issues/392